# .NET MAUI Accessing Apple Healthkit

Tags: ios, .net, maui, healthkit

I would like to access iOS Healthkit, eventually Android too but cannot find out a successful way to do it. Online I've seen advice pointing to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/healthkit which is for xamarin and not MAUI, but the methods in the example are not found. This is the code:

```
private HKHealthStore healthKitStore = new HKHealthStore ();

public override void OnActivated (UIApplication application)
{
    ValidateAuthorization ();
}

private void ValidateAuthorization ()
{
    var heartRateId = HKQuantityTypeIdentifierKey.HeartRate;
    var heartRateType = HKObjectType.GetQuantityType (heartRateId);
    var typesToWrite = new NSSet (new [] { heartRateType });
    var typesToRead = new NSSet ();
    healthKitStore.RequestAuthorizationToShare (
            typesToWrite, 
            typesToRead, 
            ReactToHealthCarePermissions);
}

void ReactToHealthCarePermissions (bool success, NSError error)
{
    var access = healthKitStore.GetAuthorizationStatus (HKObjectType.GetQuantityType (HKQuantityTypeIdentifierKey.HeartRate));
    if (access.HasFlag (HKAuthorizationStatus.SharingAuthorized)) {
            HeartRateModel.Instance.Enabled = true;
    } else {
            HeartRateModel.Instance.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately,

```
HKQuantityTypeIdentifierKey.HeartRate;
HKObjectType.GetQuantityType (heartRateId);
```

Seem to be missing. Has anyone got a working example for MAUI?

Comment: Given that this is iOS specific code, did you put it in a class in your iOS folder?

Comment: Absolutely, inside appdelegate.

Comment: You have `using HealthKit;` at top of file?  If you remove `.HeartRate`, then type `.`, does intellisense show any choices at all, for `HKQuantityTypeIdentifierKey` members?

Comment: Yep and intellisense has some HealthKit code but not HKQuantityTypeIdentifierKey. It has HKQuantityTypeIdentifier instead. Also, GetQuantityType doesn’t exist either in HKObjectType

Comment: I don't know whether Apple changed API, or whether Maui is using a newer API binding that better matches naming conventions of Apple's Healthkit. Either way, consider referring to Apple docs. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit. That, combined with Intellisense, will hopefully allow you to find the corresponding c# calls. Should be similar, except class and method names start with a capital letter (.Net convention). And sometimes a property Foo is used instead of a pair of getFoo/setFoo methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two methods in the documentation you refer to are outdated, you can modify your method as follows:

```
HKQuantityTypeIdentifierKey.HeartRate; ---> HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.HeartRate;

HKObjectType.GetQuantityType (heartRateId); ---> HKQuantityType.Create(heartRateId);
```

For more details, you can refer to:

[HealthKit Namespace | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/healthkit?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12)

[HKQuantityTypeIdentifierKey Class | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/healthkit.hkquantitytypeidentifierkey?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12)

[HKObjectType.GetQuantityType(NSString) Method | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/healthkit.hkobjecttype.getquantitytype?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12)

Answer (score 0):

I used this code in my .Net Maui app since you asked for both iOS and Android. You can see an auth request for heart rate, but the code doesn't actually query for or observe heart data. Anyway, this code is a great guide to start with. The code also implements completion handlers across iOS and Android.

https://github.com/jlmatus/Xamarin-Forms-HealthKit-steps/blob/master/StepsCounter-Test-Project/iOS/HealthData.cs

Hope this helps!